# How to load json data in easyui combobox

Tags: json, jquery-ui, combobox, jquery-easyui

I have created a json object of state after getting data from database in a jsp file and now i want to add value from json file to combobox. can anyone tell me how to add value in combobox. my code of Example.jsp file where i creates json object is

```
try{
                    String query="SELECT * from State";
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jums","root","abcdefgh");
                    Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
                    while(rs.next())
                    {
                         //int  id=rs.getInt("id");
                         //String name=rs.getString("name");
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();

                         jObj.put("id", rs.getInt("id"));
                        jObj.put("name", rs.getString("name"));
                        list.add(jObj);
                    }
                    out.print(list);
                    conn.close();
                }catch(Exception ex)
                {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Error: "+ex.getMessage());
                }
```

and i want to load name of state in a some other jsp file having combobox with code as

```
<input class="easyui-combobox" name="language" style="width:100%;" data-options="                                                                  
                                                               valueField:'id',
                                                               textField:'name',
                                                               url:'EXAMPLE.jsp',                                
                                                               label: 'State:',
                                                               labelPosition: 'top'
                                                               ">
```

but i am not getting the name of state. Please help

Answer (score 0):

EasyUI comboboxes accept data **strictly** in this json format:

[{"id":"1","name":"name_1"},{"id":"2","name":"name_2"}]

**double quotes " " included**

Thus if you're populating your json data from a Java class, ensure that you add the double quotes in side the string as well, like:

```
jObj.put("\"id\"", "\""+rs.getInt("id")"\"");
```